# My simulator is posting data to server but my device isn't

Tags: iphone, xcode, localhost, server, simulator

I've downloaded the project from https://github.com/iElmo/SQL and everything was working fine until I had tried the app on my iPhone. The simulator was doing great job and filled my database with everything I posted but somehow my iPhone is not connected to the server or what and can't fill the database on server. Please, can you help me with that, I really need your help.

Comment: Are the connection parameters configured correctly to connect to your server?

Answer (score 0):

```
#define kPostURL @"http://localhost/tutorialTest.php"
```

Are you sure, that localhost is valid server URL?
it works on simulator, because simulator and server runs in one computer.

Comment: So what do you suggest to do ? Should I change the localhost for something else ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your device and your server are in one local network, You can try to change localhost to local ip address of your server.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working finally :) I tried to change localhost to local ip address for several times but this time it surprisingly worked. This time I tried to do it with different wifi and it worked, which is nice. Probably it didn't work because of the "old" wifi. Thanks a lot again. :)